# How to delete a comment but not delete the replies, set it to say comment deleted instead?

Tags: laravel

I have a discussion forum and I want to be able for a user to delete their comment but without deleting the replies to the comment, is there a way to set it to say comment deleted or something, while actually deleting it?

This is my model

```
class ForumReply extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'bulletin_id',
        'comment',
        'anonymous'
    ];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function discussionForum()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DiscussionForum::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ForumReply::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to delete something without actually deleting it, `softDeletes` is available: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting, or you could consider using a boolean flag that renders the comment differently when "deleted" (the terminology would be deleted, but it's more of a "hide" action)

Comment: @TimLewis If I use the soft deletes when do the comments actually get deleted?

Comment: They will get "deleted" in the sense that they won't show up in your app unless you use the `->withTrashed()` method, but they will still be in your database, with a column `deleted_at` set to a timestamp. If you call `forceDelete()`, then they are nuked from the database.

Comment: If you do not want to use `softDeletes`, what you can do is make `parent_id` null on all child comments and then delete the parent comment.

Comment: @user3532758 I'm testing the `->onDelete('set null');` function on the migrations, If I wanted to keep the comment in the forums as the parent comment but set the data or something as just `'comment deleted'` could I still use this? Right now it sets the parent_id to null, and I can delete the comment but then the replies become parent comments and won't make sense to someone reading without having seen the original parent comment.

Comment: The easiest option for your case is the one @TimLewis suggested. Use `softDeletes` and get data using `withTrashed` method. During display you can use `if($comment->trashed())` to display the message you want.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't unset `parent_id`, as you're correct, that dissociates it from the parent and wouldn't make sense when displayed. The above is correct; `->trashed()` is a `boolean` that determines if a comment has been soft deleted, and you can use that to render "Comment Deleted" instead of the comment, but keep the structure and relationships intact.

Comment: @TimLewis I ended up make a boolean in the `forum_replies` table called deleted, and when the comment is "deleted" it saved that as true and I check for that variable when displaying the comments and is its true I display something else. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good! That's essentially how `softDeletes()` work, but a little simpler. Feel free to add that a solution below and accept it (when you can) to properly close the question.